# How can I read a file from a c# project using a c dll?

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio-2010, dll

Been searching high and low for this one and can't seem to figure it out.

So I'm making a web application in visual studio using c# project. There is another project in my solution, it's a c project that compiles to dll. I've gotten to the point where I can pass information between the two and it's working right.

In my application, the user uploads a file and it is saved to the file system in an "includes" folder. The dll (compiled from c code I got from an sdk) is supposed to read in that file and decode it. The dll project works fine when I compile it as an exe and send it a file path.

My question is, how can I get the DLL (now in the bin folder) to skip back a directory and grab this file? I've tried just hardcoding the file path into the c code but it doesn't work.

```
FILE *fp;
bool isWorking = false
if(fp = fopen("../Include/testFile.fit", "r"))
    isWorking = true
```

I've also tried just writing to a text file from the DLL, hoping to find where it pops out and use that directory as a reference but the c code isn't creating and saving a file at all in that case.

Comment: I would advise against using your application folder as a file storage. I've always found it good practice to separate the two, or at least make sure the files are in a single fixed folder (full path can be hardcoded or setup in a config file) rather than using relative filepaths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the DLL file in the file system is not important. The important part is where the resulting binary is run and what it sees as its current working directory.

If your C# program uses the DLL, the code in the DLL will be run with the same current working directory as the C# program (unless you change it in the code in your DLL).

So, you should try to load your file in the same way, with regards to path, as if you were to load it from your C# program.

Comment: That's what I originally thought but it doesn't open the file and I can't think of a good way to debug it.

Comment: @Ian You debug it by checking what your current working directory is in the code in the DLL. A quick debug `printf` should tell you all you need to know using http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y(VS.80).aspx

Comment: How can execute a printf from the dll? Can't get a console from the c program.

Comment: Okay, made some progress, just need a little bit more help. I found that if I give my c program an absolute path to the txt file on my computer (c:\users\me\documents\file.txt) it reads it just fine.

That's okay for now but I'm going to need to know how to get the relative path to a folder in my project. So if I deploy this, what's the path to that file?

Comment: @Ian If you start your C# program from a command line environment, any `printf` calls from your C DLL _should_ end up there. Using this, you can find out what the current working directory is. Another way might be to open a file picker dialog from the C# program and find the current working directory that way.